# Is there a quick way to delete an HTML tag pair in vscode?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, emmet

For example, before:

```
<div>
    <div>Titles</div>
    <div>Description</div>
</div>
```

After:

```
    <div>Titles</div>
    <div>Description</div>
```

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Use the `Emmet: Remove Tag` command:

[image]

Setup a keybinding for this with `editor.emmet.action.removeTag`:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+k",
    "command": "editor.emmet.action.removeTag"
}
```

Comment: how to remove the content too?

Comment: @NamNamNam If you want to remove the content too, use `Emmet: Balance (outwards)` to select the tag and content and then press backspace to remove it.

Comment: @mattbierner Dumb question, but where is the file located where you enter the setting snippet? (windows)

Comment: I was so hoping VS Code would have that, and it does, thank you so much!

Comment: This is extremly convenient . Thanks so much!

Comment: I can't believe how much time i've wasted finding missing ends of tags :(

Comment: Is there a way this could be applied in search and replace all? like recently in [bootstrap5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/#forms) removed `input-group-append` & `input-group-prepend` classes. It would be handy to remove all divs contain those classes. Find All & Emmet?

Comment: This does not work for react fragments (`<>` .... `</>`)

Answer (score 2):

Just a note that there is an improvement in vscode v1.63 to also (as the OP requested) remove the lines on which the removed tags reside.  It works now in the Insiders Build.  See

> #### Emmet Remove Tag command improvement
>
> The "Emmet: Remove Tag" command now removes empty lines around tags if
> they are the only tags on the line. It also now does not take into
> account empty lines when calculating the amount to reindent the lines.

See [release notes: emmet remove tag improvements](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_63.md#emmet-remove-tag-command-improvement)

```html
<div>                   <- this entire line will be removed sonce only the tag on the line
    <div>Titles</div>
    <div>Description</div>
</div>                  <- this entire line will be removed
```