# How setting VSCODE on HTML

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

In VSCODE, how do I delete the closing </> in the html but the parent <> doesn't get deleted too?

```
<div> <!-- 2. which even followed was deleted-->
<p>TEXT</p>
<p>TEXT</p>
<p>TEXT</p>
</div> <!-- 1. This is what you want to delete-->
```

Please help.

Comment: How is this question related to HTML?

Comment: check this [link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/html)

Comment: looks like the issue duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49336584/is-there-a-quick-way-to-delete-an-html-tag-pair-in-vscode

Answer (score 0):

Open Visual Studio Code, go to `File -> Preferences -> Settings` or use the shortcut `ctrl + ,` to open the settings.

Search for the setting `Auto Closing Tags`. Uncheck HTML: Auto Closing Tags.

[image]

These search results allow you to disable auto closing for JavaScript and TypeScript if desired.